# Decrease the latency of showing tips (like img's title)

Tags: javascript, html

When you move your mouse over a link with title, after a while it will show the title as a tip. Is it possible to remove this delay or change it so I shows the tip faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is strictly browser dependent. If you want custom tooltips you should consider a JavaScript solution.

Here's a tutorial on how to replace the browser tooltips with custom ones: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/jquery-custom-tooltips

Answer (score 3):

No, it is a browser/os configuration. Your only reliable option is replacing the default tooltip with a JavaScript tooltip, for example: [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

Answer (score 2):

You can generate something similar to those using Javascript or CSS, but you can't actually change the behavior of that since it's browser and OS dependent.